# Unir audio WAV en Python

Tags: python

tengo varios audios:

```
audio1 = "sounds/audio1.wav"
audio2 = "sounds/audio2.wav"
audio3 = "sounds/audio3.wav"
```

Lo que quiero es unirlos y crear un solo audio.

Luego de eso pretendo eliminar los espacios en blanco con el codigo que se muestra en este post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875476/editing-a-wav-files-using-python

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Hola! Has probado algo para unirlos? Te falló? Qué error salió?

Comment: Hace por favor el [tour]. recuerda aceptar las respuestas que te sirvieron!

Answer (score 2):

```
import audiolab, scipy

a, fs, enc = audiolab.wavread('audio1.wav')
b, fs, enc = audiolab.wavread('audio2.wav')
c = scipy.vstack((a,b))
audiolab.wavwrite(c, 'audio4.wav', fs, enc)

d, fs, enc = audiolab.wavread('audio3.wav')
e, fs, enc = audiolab.wavread('audio4.wav')
f = scipy.vstack((d,e))
audiolab.wavwrite(f, 'audio5.wav', fs, enc)
```

Puedes unir audio1.wav y audio2.wav en audio4.wav y, a continuación, unir audio3.wav y audio4.wav en audio5.wav

De esta forma, el resultado, audio5.wav, es la unión de tus 3 archivos de audio.

[Fuente (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890703/how-to-join-two-wav-files-using-python)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Me funciono lo siguiente, sin tener que instalar alguna dependencia:

```
import wave

infiles = ["audio1.wav", "audio2.wav"]
outfile = "sounds.wav"

data= []
for infile in infiles:
    w = wave.open(infile, 'rb')
    data.append( [w.getparams(), w.readframes(w.getnframes())] )
    w.close()

output = wave.open(outfile, 'wb')
output.setparams(data[0][0])
output.writeframes(data[0][1])
output.writeframes(data[1][1])
output.close()
```

Comment: Recuerda que, en un rato, podrás marcar tu respuesta como aceptada.